# OpenShot not working Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: 22.04, openshot

1st of all I'm very noob in linux..I could run Openshot on ubuntu 20.04 but recently I did new clean install of 22.04 and now I can't run Openshot. I installed it through github repo,,as mention worked on 20 but not on 22.04 .

When I click openshot from launcher (show application) it does nothing.can it be it's not updated for 22.04?but I downloaded latest version of Openshot which is released after 22.04 is released.

Comment: OpenShot is available in the Ubuntu Universe repository. That is the tested version.

Comment: how can i install it?from Universe repo?

Comment: As usual, with the Ubuntu Software or in terminal: `sudo apt install openshot-qt`

Comment: There is a review on the download page in Ubuntu Software that suggests the Ubuntu version doesn't work with `wayland` the default windowing system in 22.04. That may not be the case in X11 (not tried it).

Comment: @ChanganAuto Ubuntu software has 2.5.1 installed it but doesn't work,,I installed 2.6.1 from the page still it didn't work..But why did it run on 20.04 then?

Comment: @24601 mine is showing X11 but not working

Comment: Are you using the repository version of openshot or some manually installed version from GitHub?

Comment: at last,,after nothing working (tried from ubuntu software,from their website,github, even the .appimage ones..but nothing worked) I just found daily builds (tried daily build appimage didn't work) which is the PPA ones and at last it's working..

Comment: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openshot.developers/libopenshot-daily
sudo apt update
sudo apt install openshot-qt python3-openshot

ONLY this worked for me,,no matter what else I tried,it didn't open

Comment: Reported as Bug #1971094: [openshot doesn't start Ubuntu 22.04 fresh install](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openshot-qt/+bug/1971094)

Comment: I added that repository but the installed version crashed. It's an unstable developer version so it is not necessarily going to be stable long-run. I don't want an unstable version, I want a stable version. I used this as production software and it is now broken and I cannot find a workaround. Yet another aspect of Ubuntu that broke with the upgrade to 22. My system is almost unusable and I am going to have to change distros, this is only one of dozens of things that broke. The release clearly was not ready.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in OpenShot itself. To quote the bug report:

> openshot doesn't start Ubuntu 22.04 fresh install

You can follow the full discussion, including potential solutions, [on the bug report page](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openshot-qt/+bug/1971094).

Comment: I haven't gotten anything recommended there to work. There are a lot of competing recommendations and some of them are dated and solutions that might have worked in the past might no longer work. Have you found a solution that works for you?

Answer (score 0):

This method works 2024 01 16
Install OpenShot in Ubuntu 22.04:

1. Kill any running hung bad version of openshot.
2. Uninstall any installed openshot (sudo apt-get remove.....)
3. In a terminal run  gnome-software
4. At the top of the panel click on the (search) magnifying glass.
5. Type in OpenShot
6. Follow the instructions to install.